# Password in PDF and customized footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation

I have a PDF file, which is a course, our company plans to make it available to a online course users.

To do this, I have to add password to open the file on the machine of the person, and a custom footer, something like this:

"This copy is licensed to Thiago A. Klein, Member ID: 56789. The copy, reproduction or sale are prohibited."

I'm working on a rails applications.

Does anyone have any idea, Rails Gem or service that does this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Prawn for PDF generation--it can do security measures like a password.

Here is the link for more information https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn

Put `gem 'prawn'` in your Gemfile to install it.

Security information: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/tree/master/manual/security

Comment: Hi, did this end up helping you? If so, please remember to select it as the correct answer and upvote it. Thanks!